# How to run .rb file with specific version of cucumber when multiple versions are installed

Tags: rubygems

I am trying to execute feature files with specific cucumber version when multiple cucumber versions are installed.
Can somebody help on this.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `bundler` to manage your gem version

First install bundler if you have not, open your terminal window and run this command:

```
gem install bundler
```

Specify your dependencies in a `Gemfile` in your project's root with the cucumber version, Eg. cucumber version you wanted is 1.0.1.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'cucumber', '1.0.1'
```

Run the command after creating the `Gemfile`

```
bundle install
```

This should generate the `Gemfile.lock`

To run the specific cucumber script.

Eg. you have been running using `ruby script.rb`

you would need to run `bundle exec ruby script.rb`